# Get all categories

Tags: magento-1.8, category, topmenu

There are a few answers related to this but the problem I am facing is a little different. I'm only getting categories that are set as visible in Navigation Menu

[image]

It happens, for example, when I try to get all categories I have to show them with `Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories();`

It seemed to give me all categories but it didn't. There are like 10 main categories that I don't include in Navigation Menu with that option to avoid too many categories on the top of the page. Instead, I have an static cms named `more` where I add those 10 manually at the end of the navigation menu.

So, what I'm asking is if there is a way to get all categories or another way to add these 10 categories in a single menu tab with the navigation menu activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy this code on your magento root dir and run it from url.

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '600M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin'); 
    ?>
    <?php
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();
       $products_row = array();
    foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
    {
        $data = array();
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
        if($_category->getIsActive()) {
            $data[] =   $_category->getName();
            $data[] =   str_replace('/getCat.php','',$_category->getURL()); 
            $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
            $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
            foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
            {
                $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
                if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                    $data[] = $_category->getName().' >> '.$_sub_category->getName();           
                    $data[] =   str_replace('/getCat.php','',$_sub_category->getURL()); 

                    $sub_sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
                    $sub_sub_subcats = $sub_sub_cat->getChildren();
                    foreach(explode(',',$sub_sub_subcats) as $sub_sub_subCatid)
                    {
                        $_sub_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_sub_subCatid);
                        if($_sub_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                            $data[]= $_category->getName().' >> '.$_sub_category->getName().' >> '.$_sub_sub_category->getName();
                            $data[] = str_replace('/getCat.php','',$_sub_sub_category->getURL());   

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        $products_row[] = $data; 
    }
     echo '<pre>';
    print_r($products_row);
     echo '<pre>';
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: erm mind going into a bit more details on what it should achieve? I assume it is for testing purpose only. Otherwise I don't see why you'd have to put it in your root dir instead of creating a page/template.

Comment: you can also create template file  using this code.

Comment: This worked, it shows all categories even if they are on navigation menu or not. Thank you very much, and thank you for your fast answer too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will load all the categories even if they are not visible in the main menu.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addIsActiveFilter();

foreach($categories as $cat) {
    echo $cat->getName() . "<br>";
}
```